# pearson correlation before and after training calculate in relation to a value

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, matplotlib

I'm a beginner so please be nice.
In the photo, you can see my current status.
I had a database with different values output with the help of pandas and had the average in the last column "Votes" formed.

My concern now is to determine the Pearson correlation before and after training and to compare it at the end to what extent it changes.

The correlation should always be in relation to the last column ("Votes"), ie all other values together in relation to "Votes".

I hope it is understandable what I would like to calculate.

[image]

Comment: don't post code as images

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use Pearson's r for evaluation your model.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
preds = model.predict(normed_train_data.to_numpy())
r, p_val = pearsonr(preds, labels.to_numpy())
```

Note: You may need to reshape the inputs.

See [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)